# Can't assign FULLTEXT index on my table

Tags: mysql, database, search, expansion

I am trying to implement a search function on a database table using query expansion, and I'm aware that I have to add the FULLTEXT index on the fields I want to become searchable. I have tried to do this and got no errors from PHPMyAdmin, but when I examine the structure of the table the cardinality of the FULLTEXT index is 0. I have tried inidividually setting the FULLTEXT index and it seems to work, but my serach returns the error: 
Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the index on all fields i wanted to be searchable and in the combination I wanted to search them...

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I worked with FULLTEXT in the past but now for some reason I can't add the index

Answer (score 0):

Try executing a REPAIR on the table you have just added them to, to (re)build the fulltext indexes:

```
REPAIR table foo
```

Also note that fulltext will only work on varchar or text columns. As a last resort, I would try restarting MySql.

The following page just about covers everything:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Hope that helped.

Comment: That helped somewhat...instead of saying cardinality none, it now says 1.  Does that refer to the number of records affected or the number of columns that now have that index?  I tried re-indexing them and repairing again, but still just cardinality one, and my script still produces the same error message.  So it partly worked, but not fully.

Comment: @chibineku - are you applying a fulltext to individual columns?

Comment: The first query I made assigned it to several - 7 I think.  I have since used PHPMyAdmin to apply it to single columns in turn.

Comment: I have tried adding the index one at a time, and this works for the title field of my table, which is VARCHAR, but not for the others.  I tried the query doing only one column at a time and only the title one seems to have worked.  The rest are either VARCHAR or TEXT datatype, and after adding each one I repaired the table, so I don't see what could possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database storage engine. InnoDB do not support FULLTEXT index. Change it to MyISAM

Comment: InnoDB has supported FULLTEXT since 5.6